# Calculate attendance based on shift wise using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below tables 
trnevents for log punch:

```
emp_reader_id   DT
1066    2019-08-10 19:02:41.000
1066    2019-08-10 07:10:41.000
1066    2019-08-10 07:02:41.000
1066    2019-08-09 18:59:02.000
1066    2019-08-09 07:00:12.000
1066    2019-08-08 18:57:49.000
1066    2019-08-08 07:02:14.000
1066    2019-08-07 18:55:37.000
1066    2019-08-07 07:01:27.000
1066    2019-08-06 18:57:29.000
1066    2019-08-06 07:01:10.000
```

Below are Shift Schedule to employee on datewise:

```
emp_reader_id   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  
   1066         14  14  14  14  14  13  13
```

Shift_days :

```
shift_id    day_start_time  night_shift day_end_time
      13       7.00            0           19.00
      14       19.00           1           7.00
```

My query:

```
update A set Belongs_to=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(d, -1, A.DT) , 23),EventCatId=1
      from dbo.trnevents A    
      LEFT JOIN dbo.shift_schedule SS ON A.emp_reader_id = SS.emp_reader_id 
      AND YEAR(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=SS.year_no AND MONTH(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=SS.month_no
      LEFT JOIN dbo.shift  ON dbo.shift.shift_id = CASE      WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=1 THEN SS.[1]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=2 THEN SS.[2]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=3 THEN SS.[3]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=4 THEN SS.[4]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=5 THEN SS.[5]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=6 THEN SS.[6]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=7 THEN SS.[7]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=8 THEN SS.[8]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=9 THEN SS.[9]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=10 THEN SS.[10]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=11 THEN SS.[11]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=12 THEN SS.[12]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=13 THEN SS.[13]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=14 THEN SS.[14]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=15 THEN SS.[15]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=16 THEN SS.[16]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=17 THEN SS.[17]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=18 THEN SS.[18]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=19 THEN SS.[19]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=20 THEN SS.[20]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=21 THEN SS.[21]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=22 THEN SS.[22]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=23 THEN SS.[23]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=24 THEN SS.[24]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=25 THEN SS.[25]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=26 THEN SS.[26]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=27 THEN SS.[27]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=28 THEN SS.[28]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=29 THEN SS.[29]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=30 THEN SS.[30]
                                                                WHEN DAY(DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT))=31 THEN SS.[31] END
      LEFT JOIN dbo.shift_days ON dbo.shift.shift_id = dbo.shift_days.shift_id 
      and day_id = datepart(dw,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),  DATEADD(d, 0, A.DT), 23))
     where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.DT, 23) between  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(d, 1, @start_date), 23) and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(d, 1, @end_date), 23) 
          and A.DT < isnull(DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, DATEADD(d, 0, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.DT, 23))))+
                              CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND, 
                                 DATEDIFF(SECOND, '02:00:00.0000000',cast(replace(cast(dbo.shift_days.day_start_time as varchar(7)),'.',':') as time)), 
                                      '00:00:00'), 8),(DATEADD(d, 0, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.DT, 23))  + '10:00:00')) 
  and  A.emp_reader_id in (select distinct emp_reader_id from daily_attendance_data
  where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),att_date, 23) =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(d, -1, A.DT), 23) and night_shift=1)
```

My Output:

```
emp_reader_id      DT                Belongs_to
    1066    2019-08-10 07:02:41     2019-08-10
    1066    2019-08-09 18:59:02     2019-08-09
    1066    2019-08-09 07:00:12     2019-08-08
    1066    2019-08-08 18:57:49     2019-08-08
    1066    2019-08-08 07:02:14     2019-08-07
    1066    2019-08-07 18:55:37     2019-08-07
```

9th day night shift-[18:59]-[7:02]
10th day shift. [7:00]-[19:00]
But belongs to date not updated to 9th , it assign to 10th.

> 2019-08-09 18:59:02.000 to 2019-08-10 07:02:41.000

My Expected output:

```
 emp_reader_id      DT                Belongs_to
     1066    2019-08-10 19:02:41     2019-08-10
     1066    2019-08-10 07:05:41     2019-08-10
     1066    2019-08-10 07:02:41     2019-08-09
     1066    2019-08-09 18:59:02     2019-08-09
     1066    2019-08-09 07:00:12     2019-08-08
     1066    2019-08-08 18:57:49     2019-08-08
     1066    2019-08-08 07:02:14     2019-08-07
     1066    2019-08-07 18:55:37     2019-08-07
```

Kindly help me to sort out this.

Comment: why the rows in `Shift Schedule` are duplicated ?

Comment: row 2 and 3 of the expected output. Both have same `DT` of `2019-08-10 07:xx` why one belongs to `2019-08-10` and another `2019-08-09`

Comment: @Squirrel 2019-08-09 18:59:02    night shift ends at mrng 07:02:41 and again he start his next duty 07:05:41 - 19:02:41 full day shift

Comment: how do you know `07:02:41` is ending  and not beginning of shift ? Isn't your shift cross over time is `07:00` ? So isn't it should be beginning of shift ?

Comment: Yes start from 7.00 , is ther any way

Comment: @Dolubolu, if you use SQL Server 2012+ and if your data doesn't have missing or duplicate events (each shift has exactly one start event and exactly one end event), then you can use `LEAD` or `LAG` functions to efficiently put your events in pairs.

Comment: Your query and wrong output is not require .It is creating confusion.Just mention what is your real table data and what is your expected output. Shift Schedule table is not clear .Can you explain relation between all 3 tables.

Comment: It is very unclear what the relationships of the tables are, what is shift schedule table and how does it relate to the other tables. You show output, yet your main query is an update, should it be SELECT? Please post table structures, perhaps even create a SQLFIDDLE example.

Answer (score 2):

Case 1# : Suppose Emp Actual In time is `19:00` and  Log in time is 
`2019-08-06 17:00:00`,then you have to determine whether this is Early come of 
`2019-08-06` or Over time of `2019-08-05`.There are many example like this,

You have to make certain rule regarding this.

In my script I have followed this with Column `MarginShiftStart` and `MarginShiftEnd`.
So suppose Actual In time is `19:00` and Emp log In time is `2019-08-06 16:00:00`.
Then my script will understand that in time on `2019-08-06` is `16:00:00` and it is Early come by (180 minute or 3 hour).

This is clear or not ?

So you have to fix certain time for it.

```
declare @From Datetime='2019-08-01'
declare @To Datetime='2019-08-31'

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Calendar', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Calendar;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Shift', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Shift;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Emp_Shift', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Emp_Shift;

declare @MarginStart int=4*60
declare @MarginEnd int=8*60

create table #Emp_Shift(emp_reader_id int,ShiftDays int,ShiftID int)
insert into #Emp_Shift values(1066,5,14),(1066,6,14),(1066,7,14)
,(1066,8,14),(1066,9,14),(1066,10,13),(1066,11,13)


create table #Shift(shift_id int,day_start_time time(0)
, night_shift bit,day_end_time time(0),DutyMinute int)
insert into #Shift(shift_id,day_start_time,night_shift,day_end_time,DutyMinute)
values
      (13,cast('07:00' as time(0)) ,0,cast('19:00'as time(0)),12*60)
     ,(14,cast('19:00' as time(0)),1,cast('07:00'as time(0)),12*60)


Create table #Calendar(AttnDt Datetime)
insert into #Calendar(AttnDt)
select Dates from CalendarDate where dates between @From and @To

create table #temp (emp_reader_id int, DT  datetime)
insert into #temp values
 (1066,'2019-08-10 19:02:41') 
,(1066,'2019-08-10 07:05:41') 
,(1066,'2019-08-10 07:02:41') 
,(1066,'2019-08-09 18:59:02') 
,(1066,'2019-08-09 07:00:12') 
,(1066,'2019-08-08 18:57:49') 
,(1066,'2019-08-08 07:02:14') 
,(1066,'2019-08-07 18:55:37') 


;
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT AttnDt,
                emp_reader_id,
                ShiftID,
                AttnDt + CAST(day_start_time AS DATETIME) AS ActualShiftStart,
                DATEADD(MINUTE, DutyMinute, (AttnDt + CAST(day_start_time AS DATETIME))) AS ActualShiftEnd
         FROM #Calendar C
              LEFT JOIN #Emp_Shift ES ON DAY(c.AttnDt) = es.ShiftDays
              LEFT JOIN #Shift S ON s.shift_id = es.ShiftID),
     CTE1
     AS (SELECT *,
                DATEADD(minute, -@MarginStart, ActualShiftStart) MarginShiftStart,
                DATEADD(minute, @MarginEnd, ActualShiftEnd) MarginShiftEnd
         FROM CTE)
     SELECT a.*,
            DATEDIFF(minute, InTime, OutTime) TimeWork,
            CASE
                WHEN InTime > ActualShiftStart
                THEN DATEDIFF(minute, ActualShiftStart, InTime)
            END LateBy,
            CASE
                WHEN ActualShiftEnd > OutTime
                THEN DATEDIFF(minute, OutTime, ActualShiftEnd)
            END EarlyGoing,
            OutTime
     FROM CTE1 A
          OUTER APPLY
     (
         SELECT MIN(DT) InTime,
                MAX(dt) OutTime
         FROM #temp t
         WHERE t.DT >= a.MarginShiftStart
               AND t.dt <= MarginShiftEnd
     ) t;
```

1. Depending upon actual requirement and number of rows generated,this script can be optimized.
2. Calender table can be permanent and if you 1 or 2 month attendance is to be generated then #Calendar can be generated from it.In my script CalendarDate is permanent table.You can generate data of #Calendar in whatever way you like.
3. [#Shift] : In this table I am not using `day_end_time` because it is very hard to calculate thing.I am using day_start_time and DutyMinute to calculate end time.
4. [#Emp_Shift] : Your way of storing Shift ID day wise is wrong.It is hard to manipulate in that manner.You better change or Pivot your table according to `#Emp_Shift`.
5. you can analyse `Select * from CTE` to actually see how data is generated.
6. you can again do `Select * from CTE1` to check `MarginShiftStart` and `MarginShiftEnd`. If this is not clearen you can ask me with example.
7. It is better idea to Index Tune after query is complete with requirement and with actual data.Like you will be generating `Attendance of 500 emp for one month` or so.If script is ok then you can come with actual scenario.

Create Calendar Table,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CalendarDate](
[Dates] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Dates] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

　

insert into [CalendarDate] with(tablock)
select top (1000000) 
dateadd(day,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null)),'1949-12-31 00:00:00') 
from sys.objects a, sys.objects b, sys.objects c
```

Answer (score 0):

Can check below query if it helps

```
    Select emp_reader_id, DT,
    case when convert(char(8), DT, 108) 
     BETWEEN
    day_starttime and day_endtime  
    When
    shifttime=0 then
    convert(char(8), DT, 111)  ELSE 
     convert(char(8), DT+1, 111)  
      End as "belongs to" 
     From
    Trnevents
```

The above query is a sample I havent joined it but it checks the time falling in between start time and end time if it meets then the same date is the op else date +1

Answer (score 0):

I working on your query. Please check below queries. It might be useful.

```
--Step 1.----------------------------------
create table trnevents 
(
emp_reader_id int,
DT datetime
)

insert into trnevents values
(1066,'2019-08-10 19:02:41.000'),
(1066,'2019-08-10 07:10:41.000'),
(1066,'2019-08-10 07:02:41.000'),
(1066,'2019-08-09 18:59:02.000'),
(1066,'2019-08-09 07:00:12.000'),
(1066,'2019-08-08 18:57:49.000'),
(1066,'2019-08-08 07:02:14.000'),
(1066,'2019-08-07 18:55:37.000'),
(1066,'2019-08-07 07:01:27.000'),
(1066,'2019-08-06 18:57:29.000'),
(1066,'2019-08-06 07:01:10.000')

--Step 2.-------------------------------------
create table emp_shift
(
emp_reader_id int,
shift_date date,
shift_id int
)

insert into emp_shift values
(1066,'2019-08-05',14),
(1066,'2019-08-06',14),
(1066,'2019-08-07',14),
(1066,'2019-08-08',14),
(1066,'2019-08-09',14),
(1066,'2019-08-10',13),
(1066,'2019-08-11',13)

--Step 3.-----------------------------------
create table shift_master
(
shift_id int,
shift_start_time time,
shift_end_time time,
night_shift bit
)

insert into shift_master values
(13,'07:00','19:00',0),
(14,'19:00','07:00',1)

--Step 3. Create temporary table for workings--

select *,cast('N' as varchar(2)) as updatetag,CAST('' as datetime) as belongs_to into #tmptrnevents from trnevents

--Step 5. Getting date belongs to.

declare @emp_reader_id int, @shift_date date,@night_shift bit
declare @start datetime,@end datetime

declare  cur_shift cursor
FOR SELECT a.emp_reader_id,a.shift_date,b.night_shift 
FROM emp_shift a
inner join  shift_master b
on a.shift_id=b.shift_id order by a.shift_date
    OPEN cur_shift  
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_shift into @emp_reader_id , @shift_date ,@night_shift  
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN

         if (@night_shift=1) --if it is night shift
         begin
         select @start=isnull(MAX(dt),@shift_date)  from #tmptrnevents where emp_reader_id=@emp_reader_id and cast(DT as date)=@shift_date  and updatetag='N' 
         select @end=isnull(MIN(dt),@shift_date)  from #tmptrnevents where emp_reader_id=@emp_reader_id and cast(DT as date)=dateadd(d,1,@shift_date)  and updatetag='N' --to get next day shift
         end

         if (@night_shift=0) --if it is not night shift
         begin
         select @start=isnull(MIN(dt),@shift_date), @end= isnull(MAX(dt),@shift_date) from #tmptrnevents where emp_reader_id=@emp_reader_id and cast(DT as date)=@shift_date  and updatetag='N' 
         end

         update #tmptrnevents set belongs_to= @shift_date,updatetag='Y' where emp_reader_id=@emp_reader_id and DT between @start and @end

         FETCH NEXT FROM cur_shift into @emp_reader_id , @shift_date ,@night_shift  

        END  

    CLOSE cur_shift  
    DEALLOCATE cur_shift  

    select emp_reader_id,DT,belongs_to from #tmptrnevents

    drop table #tmptrnevents
```

Comment: I would be surprised if a cursor is required for this. Cursors generally are a bad idea as SQL is a SET Based language and by using a cursor you are forcing SQL Server to use a Row By Agonising Row (RBAR) approach. It is rare that a cursor based approach can't be replaced with a SET based approach and yield significant performance gains. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/03/18/increase-your-sql-server-performance-by-replacing-cursors-with-set-operations/

Comment: I worked based on output. Set based process might be helpful. Will check your link.